# Creating chart using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, dynamic, charts

Does somebody know how to create a chart by code? C#, Visual Studio 2010. (Form application)If i use the "drag" method (if i add manually) the generated code is

`private System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart chart1;`

but when i'm trying to use the same thing just don't work. I cant find out witch witch "using" should i use. It looks like  "System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization" doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the actual .DLL of the datavisualization. You need to download the .dll from Microsoft or should be in there. Try compiling the project.

Comment: You need to import the dll and reference the dll and then do like Chart _chart = new Chart();. Try compiling your project.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a assembly reference to `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization`. Then you can write:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart _MyChart;
```

or

```
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
private Chart _MyChart;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [FusionCharts](http://fusioncharts.com/).

It is a JavaScript charting library. However, they provide a .dll file that you can import in your Visual Studio project and auto-generate the HTML + JavaScript code.

Here is a [tutorial series](http://blog.fusioncharts.com/2012/03/javascript-charts-using-sql-server-data-with-fusioncharts-xt-part-2/) from their blog.